# jQuery Validate Triggering message from success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to figure out once the callback to the remote function is made for either the username or email address, that if the data returned is equal to "n" it should trigger the message to be displayed.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $("form").validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 12,
                remote: {
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'register/is_username_available',
                    data: {
                        'username': function() {
                            return $('#username').val();
                        }
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        if (data == 'y') {
                            alert('available');
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('no available');
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            email_address: {
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'register/is_email_available',
                    data: {
                        'email_address': function() {
                            return $("#email_address").val();
                        }
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        if (data == 'y') {
                            alert('available');
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('no available');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                remote: 'The username is already in use'
            },
            email_address: {
                remote: 'There is already an account set up that uses that email address!'
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: I recommend that you rephrase your question; I think it could be made clearer.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do, what you're expecting to happen, and what's actually happening.

Comment: All i want to know now is when the data is NOT "y" then it triggers the messages below.

Comment: What is actually happening, then?

Comment: Do you have a live demo, or a fiddle?

Comment: No I just want it to trigger the validation messages when the data returns back as NOT being "y"

Comment: Where have you declared what "y" is?

Comment: Do you not see my code above where it says data == "y". So again I iterate when data is not equal to "y" instead of it alerting "not available" I want it to trigger the validation message for username or email.

Comment: Yes, but do you mean the text character "y", "y" a variable somewhere, etc.

Comment: Which coincidently has nothing to do with what I'm asking about. I just want to know how to have it instead display the messages of the email and username instead of the alert ('not available')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "dataType" is incorrect.. right now your telling it to get and use JSON, you on the other hand are outputting or expecting a string or "text"/"html" rather than "json"

change your dataType to html or text, and see how that does ya.

if you wanted to keep it at json.. your output from the php side would have to be

`{"response":"y"}`

and your javascript in the sucess would have to be like

`if(data.response == "y")`